# Looking for a Geoda map with OECD countries

Tags: geospatial

For my undergraduate thesis I must do a spatial analysis over the OECD countries, but I cannot find a map for them, due to them being so spread apart. Funny thing, even my spatial analysis teacher couldn't do it, so I am wondering if there is any way you know about doing it?

Comment: Useful resources:
1. https://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/3a_mapping/lab3a.html
2. https://spatial.uchicago.edu/sample-data